# Path of glassfish 3.1.1

Tags: glassfish, installation, suse

I searched google for an answer for this question but I haven't got the exact answer. I want to install glassfish in Suse linux server. I downloaded glassfish3.sh from oracle but when I run that script, the folder where glassfish is installed is `/home/$user/glassfish` and I want to change it.

Does someone know how to change the path of glassfish 3.1.1 in ubuntu server? (only terminal)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You downloaded the `.sh` file. This will always install `GlassFish` into the user's home directory. In order to install it into different directory it is a little bit more work to do.

Download and unzip the file. For e.g. you want glassfish to be in: `/opt/glassfish`:

```
wget http://download.java.net/glassfish/3.1.1/release/glassfish-3.1.1.zip
sudo unzip glassfish-3.1.1.zip -d /opt
```

That is it. `Glassfish` is installed and you can start and use it. But don't forget that you did not configure any automatic start up scripts to glassfish start up automatically.

In order to do that, run this command in your shell:

```
sudo vim /etc/init.d/glassfish
```

Paste this content: (first make change that is appropriate to you)

```
#!/bin/bash

GLASSFISH_HOME=/opt/glassfish3
case "$1" in
start)
    ${GLASSFISH_HOME}/bin/asadmin start-domain domain1
    ;;
stop)
    ${GLASSFISH_HOME}/bin/asadmin stop-domain domain1
    ;;
restart)
    ${GLASSFISH_HOME}/bin/asadmin stop-domain domain1
    ${GLASSFISH_HOME}/bin/asadmin start-domain domain1
    ;;
*)
    echo "usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
    ;;
esac    
exit 0
```

The last thing is to make the script executable by running these commands:

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/glassfish
sudo update-rc.d /etc/init.d/glassfish defaults
```

Now you can start, stop and restart glassfish like this:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/glassfish start
sudo /etc/init.d/glassfish stop
sudo /etc/init.d/glassfish restart
```